# how to implement double pointer with OpenCl rand with android JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, opencl

I am currently using an implementation of `OpenCL` bound with `JNI` interface to my android app.

When the kernel is loaded

```
__kernel void someFunction( __global double* out,
```

I get this error :

```
 error: use of type 'double' requires cl_khr_fp64 extension to be enabled
    __global double* weight_coef,
```

I tried to replace it by float and it works but I want to avoid that !

Comment: Enable the cl_khr_fp64 extension perhaps?

Comment: @shark sure but how can you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the 'cl_khr_fp64' extension.

To do that, you need to do

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
```

before any double-precision data type is initialized in the kernel code.

For further information, feel free to refer to the Khronos OpenCL specification:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_fp64.html